# How to pass data from view to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I'd like to actualise the function that current_user answers a question. In order to achieve it, I need to pass question_id data from view to controller.
In particular,

1) Pass question_id from views/homes/popular.html.erb to answers_controller.rb

2) Pass question_id from answers_controller.rb to views/answers/new.html.erb

3) Pass question_id from views/answers/new.html.erb to answers_controller.rb

I'd like to pass question_id to hogehoge at answers_controller.rb. Could you tell me how to do it?

```
#app/controllers/homes_controller.rb
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def popular
    @questions = Question.all
    @questions.each do |question|
      @answer = question.answers.highest
    end
  end
end

#app/views/homes/popular.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
     <h3>Popular</h3>
     <% @questions.each do |question| %>
       <li><%= link_to question.body, new_answer_path ,question_id:question.id%></li>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def create
    @answer = current_user.answers.create(answer_params)
    if @answer.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def answer_params
      hogehoge
    end
end

#app/views/answers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @answer, :url => answers_path do |f| %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h2>Please answer</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: To send data from view to controller you can use query string as you used in `popular.html.erb`  and in answer controller you get data in `params[:question_id]` , use instance variable in new action as @question = params[:question_id] and in `answer/new.html` use hidden field  `f.hidden_field :@question` to send data.

Comment: Dear Pardeep
By useing f.hidden_field, I've got it! Thank you!

Comment: great!!, its my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send data from view to controller you can use query string as you used in popular.html.erb and in answer controller you get data in `params[:question_id]` , use instance variable in new action as `@question = params[:question_id]` and in `answer/new.html` use hidden field `f.hidden_field :@question` to send data.